# Auto Layout - UILabel inside UITableViewCell is not wrapping on initial load for iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I am seeing a weird issue with `UILabel` wrapping in my custom `UITableViewCell`. I am using auto-layout and while this works fine on iOS > 6, the `UILabel` inside `UITableViewCell` is not wrapping on first load for iOS 6. When I tap on the cell and show details view and then come back, then UILabel wraps up as expected.

Here is how I am adding label to the cell:

```
self.productNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.productNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.productNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.productNameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
self.productNameLabel.font = kFontDynamicSubHead;
self.productNameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
self.productNameLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
[self.contentView addSubview:self.productNameLabel];
```

Then I add some constraints to position the label. I do not set any Height/Width constraint.

Finally, in my cell' `layoutSubviews` I set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` for my label.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.productNameLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.productNameLabel.bounds.size.width;
}
```

If anyone faced this before or know the workaround then kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding constraints for your `UILabel` in your code, try adding this implementation for your cell `initWithCoder`

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self =  [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {
        self.productNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.productNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.productNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.productNameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        self.productNameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        self.productNameLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

        [self setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.productNameLabel];

        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[view]-0-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:@{@"view":self.productNameLabel}]];
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[view]-0-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:@{@"view":self.productNameLabel}]];

        [self setNeedsLayout];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Hope this helps